# Filter a numpy array to retain only the running minimum?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a way to efficiently filter a numpy array to retain only the running minimum?

For example, imagine I have the array

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([ 23.,  23., 157., 226.,  23., 145., 19.,  23.,  23.])
```

I'd like to get the output

```
array([ 23.,  23., 23., 23.,  23., 23., 19.,  19.,  19.])
```

Of course I can trivially loop over it in a `for` loop but that is not very num-pythonic. Is there a better way?

Comment: `np.minimum.accumulate(arr)`